# How to connect vpn using nodejs

Tags: node.js

how to connect vpn using nodejs without port number

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you are asking about how to correctly use [getUserMedia()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

If so, then you can pass the ID of your audio / video devices in the options:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { deviceId: ... }, video: { deviceId: ... })
```

You get these IDs from another call ([enumerateDevices()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
```